# GnuPlot - Plotting fence/waterfall graph using odd .csv structure

Tags: csv, date, gnuplot, fence-plots

I'm trying to accomplish making a chart similar to the one linked below, where each line of the .csv file plots a different separated line. (I believe this is referred to as a "fence" plot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MQkJ.png

Here is what the .csv file looks like:

```
2018-01-02,1.29,1.44,1.61,1.83,1.92,2.01,2.25,2.38,2.46,2.64,2.81,2.81
2018-01-03,1.29,1.41,1.59,1.81,1.94,2.02,2.25,2.37,2.44,2.62,2.78,2.78
...
2018-06-18,1.84,1.94,2.13,2.35,2.56,2.67,2.8,2.89,2.92,2.98,3.05,3.05
```

For each date (each line), I'd like to have a different line plotted along an axis (like the diagonal axis in the aforementioned picture). The values that follow the dates are Y values, for `x=0,1,2,3,4...` being the columns.

Comment: `splot ... with zerrorfill`, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/fenceplot.html

Comment: How would I populate the line graphs with the .csv format I mentioned above, Christoph?